# Google App Engine + Python - Educational website: Required help of expert

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Currently I'm running educational website and teaching above 30,000 students. Currently this website is on Google Sites (with Google Apps). Due to few restriction and limitation, I would like to transfer this website to Google App Engine.

My requirement is Login system for this website.

I've created basic website at appspot.com. Now I would like to know that how do I make secure pages. In my website few pages are publicly available for all and others are must be secure.

Please suggest me, How do I?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't mind piggybacking on google's app administration functionality, I don't think I can provide a better answer than [google themselves](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/adminusers.html). It all looks forgiving enough.  Long story short, you need this in your app.yaml:

```
- url: <url of restricted page>
script: <script to run>
login: admim
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @rijadeja More information is needed. can you post your app.yaml?

Answer (score 1):

If by "secure" pages you mean that not admin but to distinguish between a logged in user and a logged out user you might find using the framework for user accounts that [webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com) provides for python 2.7. You can find an example app at https://github.com/fredrikbonander/Webapp2-Sample-Applications